# FindMinimum [] methods

Tags: mathematical-optimization, implementation-details

Which algorithm is used when we do not use the option Method of `FindMinimum[]` function.

```
FindMinimum[f,{x,x0}]
```

Answer (score 13):

Please, try to use the documentation search or google before posting such elementary questions. Have you at least tried? The information you want can be found in the [documentation center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html)

- With `Method->Automatic` and two starting values, `FindMinimum` uses Brent's principal axis method. With one starting value for each variable, `FindMinimum` uses BFGS quasi-Newton methods, with a limited memory variant for large systems.
- If the function to be minimized is a sum of squares, `FindMinimum` uses the Levenberg-Marquardt method (`Method->"LevenbergMarquardt"`).
- With constraints, `FindMinimum` uses interior point methods.

Comment: Indeed when one types "FindMinimum implementation" in the search bar it is the second hit for me. But perhaps they should have added a link to the implementation docs in the main entry.