# How to find which automatic method is used by FindMinimum?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, implementation-details

This question has already been addressed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181266/findminimum-how-can-i-know-which-method-mathematica-has-used) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34536/findminimum-methods). The second link consists of an answer by [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan), which clearly states which method is used in which situation. However, while trying to check out the method used [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/symbolic-and-numeric-calculus/find-the-charge-distribution-on-a-sphere.html?product=mathematica), I find that although according to the second link, the applied method should be `InteriorPoint`, the results do not match.

Can anyone please inform me of the actual method used in the given case?